# Checkbox for mvc 5 is not visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a check box in the razor view as follows

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            ////////// HERE IS THE ONE MALFUNCTIONING //////////////
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

And the above renders the following html(view source in the browser)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />

    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            ////////// THERE SEEMS TO BE SOME PROBLEM BELOW WITH THE RENDERING /////////
            <input id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" />
            <input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
            <label for="RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The model class is as follows

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

I observed that this behavior is consistent across the browsers.
So what am I missing?

**EDIT**

I dont know why but removing the dev `<div class="checkbox">` worked.

That is instead of

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            ////////// HERE IS THE ONE MALFUNCTIONING //////////////
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I have the following with one div tag removed, its now working fine. Not sure why :(. The problem is am not good at debugging css and element tree. Somehow just randomly figured this out. Thanks for all the help all of you guys.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

        ////////// This is now working fine, not sure though why //////////////
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Find it in the element tree and then check the css styles applied. That should cover whether the browser knows about it and whether it is visible.

Comment: please show the css you applied e.g. class= checkbox

Comment: I did not apply any css :(

Comment: i have tried your code it works fine

Comment: try finding ".checkbox" in all CSS files of your website and see what styles are applied there.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered this today. The culprit was some guy added this code in the main css.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Was able to check that using F12 and digging down all styles applied to my object.

In your case, you probably had something like that in your `<div class="checkbox">.`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check in `developer's option (F12)` Is it rendering the checkbox in your HTML or not.

If your HTML renders `checkbox` than check your CSS files. Search for default checkbox or something. It must be commented. That is the reason why it is not displaying it on your view.